# Ubuntu 15.10 installation fail: Starting Restore Sound Card State [fail]

Tags: system-installation, 15.10

I have been trying to get past this for the last few days.

Originally I was having an issue getting past i8042 failing, but editing the kernel to nomodeset bypasses that. I get stuck at the error in the title.

I've tried modifying acpi= a few different ways, even acpi=off. I've added noapic and nolapic.

But I just can't get anything to get me past this single error on installation.

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same issue, 'Starting Restore Card Sound State'. Eventually, I did the following. Selected 'Try Ubuntu', opened Firefox, typed login/password to my wired connection, and AFTER that, i.e. having connected, selected 'Install Ubuntu'. This worked!
P.S. When installing, I also enabled 'download updates during installation'.